# Pass an array containing input arguments to a function in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

How can I pass an array containing the dimensions I desire to a function like `ones` or `rand` in Julia?

For example, I'd like to execute

```
dims = [3 4]
rand(dims)
```

and then receive something like

```
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.300811  0.140124  0.756915   0.268328 
 0.732461  0.900773  0.251334   0.0338452
 0.54227   0.439385  0.0812104  0.612996
```

as the output.

Executing the first code block returns a single number selected at random from the array `dimen = [3 4]`, however, and `rand(dims = dimen)` returns a `ERROR: function rand does not accept keyword arguments` error.

Is there a way to do what I'm hoping to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the ["splat" operator `...`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...), as [described in the documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Varargs-Functions-1):

> On the flip side, it is often handy to "splat" the values contained in an iterable collection into a function call as individual arguments. To do this, one also uses `...` but in the function call instead

In your case:

```
julia> dims = [3 4];
julia> rand(dims...)

3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.664496  0.190208  0.167208  0.172296
 0.632465  0.374373  0.417636  0.354948
 0.743741  0.740435  0.602339  0.401814
```

Comment: Perfect! I was also trying to index an array using an array of co-ordinates and the splat operator works for that, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [splat operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#...):

```
julia> xs = [3 4]
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  4

julia> rand(xs...)
3×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.569082   0.953     0.44541   0.12763 
 0.0529293  0.470243  0.770411  0.992597
 0.15326    0.248442  0.805518  0.246996
```

The splat operator will interpolate the array into the function call's argument list.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you. You and PaSTE wrote similarly helpful answers and the answer I accept when the site lets me will be pretty much arbitrary.